# SODA API - Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#

I am using below code snippet trying to access below dataset using SODA API.

```
    **var client = new SodaClient("https://data.medicare.gov", "token code","username","password");
    var metadata = client.GetMetadata("mj5m-pzi6");**
```

I am getting the below exception message. Any pointers in resolving the below issue would be a great help. Thank you.

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Couldn't deserialize the (JSON) response into an instance of type SODA.ResourceMetadata.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": "   at SODA.SodaRequest.ParseResponse[TResult]()\r\n   at SODA.SodaClient.read[TResult](Uri uri, SodaDataFormat dataFormat)\r\n   at SODA.SodaClient.GetMetadata(String resourceId)\r\n   at POC_GetMedicareGovData.Controllers.ProviderController.Get()\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__3(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.",
    "ExceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException",
    "StackTrace": "   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)\r\n   at SODA.SodaRequest.ParseResponse[TResult]()"
```

Comment: I won't be able to help much since I'm not familiar with SodaClient, but it seems you are getting either an XML response instead of JSON or an HTML error page. Documentation suggests, that SodaClient expects `api key` as the second parameter, not an AppToken (?) so perhaps you are passing the wrong "token code" there? You are also not specifying, whether the error is thrown upon client initialization or at `clent.GetMetadata`. I assume the first?

Comment: Usually when you see `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0` it's indicative of the response being HTML or XML (not JSON). If you inspect the raw response what do you see? Is it an error page etc?

Comment: Thanks for replying. SODA.Client initialization is expecting AppToken not API token. I have tested using API token but getting an different exception. i am getting above exception on client.GetMetadata.

Comment: The weird part is code works fine some times but the same code returns exception message at client.GetMetadata line.